# Alfa 156 pollen filter leak

Tags: cabin-filter

Should I have a cover for my Alfa 156 pollen filter? I'm getting a small leak though it when it rains.

Any advice?

Comment: Please post the actual solution (text describing how to do it) as an answer to your question (and optionally accept if it works) so others know that it's how you do it

Answer (score 1):

The OP did some googling and found there should be an enclosure, which explains it.

[Here](http://www.thealfaforums.com/alfa-romeo-156/4385-156-pollen-filter.html) is the link for anyone else having the same problem.

(**NOTE:** This answer was added from what the OP edited into the question. Adding it here to actually answer the question.)